# elasticsearch query with filter by partial values

Tags: elasticsearch

am using the **Query** to fetch all the sub_attributes.id(13,15,19). bu in the result should fetch only the id which sub_attributes.id with 13, 15, & 19. not the id that I have mentioned. should fetch the partially indexed values, and using must_not, does not fetch the exact result that am expecting.

below is the query am using to fetch the values,

**Query**

```json
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "sub_attributes.id": [13, 15, 19]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```json
{
    "_index": "attrib",
    "_id": "id1",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
        "product_attribute_id": 5,
        "main_attribute_name": "Grades"
        "sub_attributes": [
            {
                "id": 13,
                "attribute_label": null,
                "attribute_value": "Grade A"
            },
            {
                "id": 14,
                "attribute_label": null,
                "attribute_value": "Grade B"
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_index": "attrib",
    "_id": "id2",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
        "product_attribute_id": 6,
        "main_attribute_name": "Operations",
        "sub_attributes": [
            {
                "id": 15,
                "attribute_label": null,
                "attribute_value": "Building"
            },
            {
                "id": 16,
                "attribute_label": null,
                "attribute_value": "Sliding"
            }
            {
                "id": 19,
                "attribute_label": null,
                "attribute_value": "Double fold"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**expected result:**

````json
{
    "_index": "attrib",
    "_id": "id1",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
        "product_attribute_id": 5,
        "main_attribute_name": "Grades",
        "sub_attributes": [
            {
                "id": 13,
                "attribute_label": null,
                "attribute_value": "Grade A"
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_index": "attrib",
    "_id": "id2",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
        "product_attribute_id": 6,
        "main_attribute_name": "Operations"
        "sub_attributes": [
            {
                "id": 15,
                "attribute_label": null,
                "attribute_value": "Building"
            },
            {
                "id": 19,
                "attribute_label": null,
                "attribute_value": "Double fold"
            }
        ]
    }
}```


want to know which term needs to be used to fetch the expected result
````

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

I don't believe you can.
Elasticsearch allow to filter documents, but not sub part of a document.

## Solution

Maybe you could modify your documents to look like:

```json
{
    "product_attribute_id": 5,
    "main_attribute_name": "Grades"
    "sub_attributes":
    {
        "id": 13,
        "attribute_label": null,
        "attribute_value": "Grade A"
    }
}
```

This will create much more documents, but easier to achieve what you want.